# $and not working in $or Means $or section not working

Tags: mongoose

```
"{"_id":ObjectId("**5c41c0ec9c06dd30e8e98b3c**"),"matchUsers":[{"_id":ObjectId("5c42d4bc87eee24a1b291b6e"),"userId":ObjectId("5c40692d47502b0a7945b114")}],"rightSwiped":[{"count":1,"_id":ObjectId("5c46c4964c9d8216ec1bf0d5"),"swipedTime":ISODate("2019-01-22T07:21:58.000Z"),"userId":ObjectId("5c456b2192c95c6003736815")}],"cupidSwiped":[{"count":2,"_id":ObjectId("5c46caf7ca46ee30f2721431"),"swipedTime":ISODate("2019-01-22T07:49:11.000Z"),"userId":ObjectId("5c456b2192c95c6003736815")}],"leftSwiped":[{"count":1,"_id":ObjectId("5c45c7d2f93046360bc4f6da"),"swipedTime":ISODate("2019-01-21T13:23:30.000Z"),"userId":ObjectId("5c41c2514e354a34f7180e85")},{"count":1,"_id":ObjectId("5c46c4964c9d8216ec1bf0d5"),"swipedTime":ISODate("2019-01-22T07:21:58.000Z"),"userId":ObjectId("5c456b2192c95c6003736815")}],"updateStatus":1,"gender":"female"}"
```

Here is a documents (above ) 
1) No error in query 
2) I want dose not return this documents according conditions
   I am all ready  left Swiped this users 
3) My id is **5c456b2192c95c6003736815**  and left swiped user id **5c41c0ec9c06dd30e8e98b3c**   
4) if swiped users (id is **5c41c0ec9c06dd30e8e98b3c**) then does not return this user in list (user list) but user in list

> ({"rightSwiped.userId":{"$ne":"my id "}})

this conditions is not working

I hope get my questions

```
{"$and":[{"_id":{"$ne":"5c456b2192c95c6003736815"}},{"updateStatus":1},{"gender":"female"},{"$or":[{"$and":[{"leftSwiped.userId":"5c456b2192c95c6003736815"},{"leftSwiped.swipedTime":{"$gte":1548056871000}}]},{"$and":[{"rightSwiped.userId":"5c456b2192c95c6003736815"},{"rightSwiped.swipedTime":{"$gte":1548056871000}}]},{"rightSwiped.userId":{"$ne":"5c456b2192c95c6003736815"}},{"leftSwiped":{"$elemMatch":{"userId":{"$ne":"5c456b2192c95c6003736815"}}}},{"userIds":{"$nin":["5c456b2192c95c6003736815"]}}]}]}
```

Comment: Hey friend above query not working 

schema data
 "rightSwiped" : [ 
        {
            "count" : 1,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c46cc25ca46ee30f272143a"),
            "swipedTime" : ISODate("2019-01-22T07:54:13.000Z"),
            "userId" : ObjectId("5c456b2192c95c6003736815")
        }
    ],

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can [edit] your question and include additional info instead of adding it in comments. Explain please, what does mean "not working" - do you get some error, unexpected result, something else?